# iOS swift add uipageviewcontroller inside of uiScrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I would like to add the uipageviewController inside UIscrollview. Everything is added as expected. But UIScrollView is not getting scrolled. Basically, the whole viewController is loaded in landscape mode. I am loading a book using UIPageViewController and adding it inside the scrollview so that users can both scroll to see the full page and also change the page that is handled using the pageviewcontroller.

That's why I am using page view controller inside scrollview

[image: Output]

```
class QuranLandController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var quranContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    // UIPageViewController
    let controller = QuranPagerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        addChildViewController(controller)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        quranContainer.layout(controller.view)
            .width().top().left().right().height(900)
//        containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
//
//        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
//            controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
//            controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
//            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
////            quranContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 900),
//            controller.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor),
//            controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)
//            ])

//        let contentRect: CGRect = quranScrollContainer.subviews.reduce(into: .zero) { rect, view in
//            rect = rect.union(view.frame)
//        }
//        quranScrollContainer.contentSize = contentRect.size

        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        //        Translator().defaultTranslation()
        for recognizer in controller.gestureRecognizers {
            if recognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer {
                recognizer.isEnabled = false
            }
        }

        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .landscapeRight
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `UIPageViewController` and put `UIViewController` with `UIScrollView` as page into it.

Each page will be scrollable to the bottom.

Comment: Well i have more tap gestures inside the each viewcontrollres of uipageview.. is there any way to make the uipagecontroller scroll ?

Comment: @AhsanAasim this is bad view hierarchy, I believe that won't work this way.

Comment: yes i understand. But my scenerio needs to be implemented that way. i have solved the scrollview scroll issue. Now problem arises with the pageviewcontrollers page swipe. it got completely disabled

Comment: @AhsanAasim try to use collection view with isPaging enabled. This won’t disable swipe.

Comment: as I need the page curl animation, that would be another issue. I have seen some apps have implemented the same thing I want to achieve. So there has to be a workaround

Comment: @AhsanAasim okay, so try to rollback to my solution. What gestures do you want to add to your page view?

Comment: Hi, I have moved to your solution. Now I have uiscrollview inside uipageview. But now scrollview is not scrolling. Do you have any example for this?